# Is the FUSE context guaranteed to be static?

Tags: c, pointers, static, fuse

In all my FUSE operations, I'm doing something like this at the beginning:

```
ctx_t* ctx = (ctx_t*)(fuse_get_context()->private_data);
```

That was getting a little tiresome, so I farmed it out to its own function where the pointer is statically defined. Is this a bad idea? Can I guarantee that the pointer will be static, so this won't cause a memory fault?

```
static ctx_t* get_ctx(void) {
  static ctx_t* ctx = NULL;

  if (ctx == NULL) {
    ctx = (ctx_t*)(fuse_get_context()->private_data);
  }

  return ctx;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return (ctx_t*)(fuse_get_context()->private_data);` from your `get_ctx` function, and just use `get_ctx`?

Comment: That's the backup plan. This way avoids repeated calls to `fuse_get_context`

Comment: You could call `fuse_get_context` and compare with the stored pointer. If they are equal return the stored one ;-)) - I really have seen such code during a review!

Comment: The [documentation for `fuse_get_context`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/fuse_chan_fd.3?query=fuse_get_context&sec=3) implies that the context is temporary (_"The returned fuse_context is only available during the lifetime of a FUSE operation."_), so I doubt it's safe.

Comment: Thanks @ColonelThirtyTwo I got the same implication, which is why I asked, but I can't see why it would need to be moved around.

Answer (score -1):

You should include this line in your header file:

```
ctx = (ctx_t*)(fuse_get_context()->private_data);
```

You will then need to call the fuse_get_context only once, that is, in your init function with `ctx` as your return value. The return value of your init function will be  passed in the private_data field of fuse_context to all file operations and as a parameter to the destroy() method. You can then pass `ctx` as one of the parameters while calling the fuse_main_function.